# Optimization causes tmpdir to fill up with 'deleted' file handle

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization, percona

Using Percona 5.6.34-79.1. Storage Engine is InnoDB.
One of the table to be optimized is 300Gb in size. 
*tmpdir* is a separate partition, and *datadir* is separate.

*datadir* has 500Gb of space, so optimize should work (taking its time).
*tmpdir* has less space than table size.

Its a standby slave, so no query of any kind is hitting this db instance, so tmpdir partition is un-used. Before I run any query, if I do **lsof | grep -i deleted**, I don't see any thing related to mysql.

Once I fire the optimize command, the *tmpdir* starts to fill up, and doing **lsof | grep -i deleted** shows large number of deleted but yet held files related to mysql.

Also on the *datadir*, the new file by the name *#sql-ib4586-1246909784.ibd* forms but remains in few kilobyte in size.

Normally tmpdir should not fill up and the new file (#sql-ib4586-1246909784.ibd) should increase in size taking up datadir space. Why is that not happening?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  Can't be done.

Long answer:  There is a glimmer of hope...

Assuming that the optimized table will still be more than 200GB, you cannot successfully run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` in the small space you allotted.  Are there other things you can delete?  Can you `OPTIMIZE` the smaller tables first - that might free enough room.  I assume you have `innodb_file_per_table=ON`?  How big is `ibdata1`?

Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename'`.

Please explain why you want to run `OPTIMIZE`.  It is rarely worth doing for InnoDB tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your other option is to use pt-online-schema-change or similar to rebuild the table. This will create an actual copy of the table on the data directory so you do not need to fill your tmpdir - it is also non-blocking.

```
pt-online-schema-change --alter='ENGINE=InnoDB' h=localhost,D=db,t=table
```